# gRPC server complaining that message is larger than max size when it's not

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm sending a HTTP2 request created by hand (using nghttp2) to a gRPC server, but it's not being handled as expected.

I'm getting this error message in the 200 OK response from the server:

`Header: grpc-status: 8`
`Header: grpc-message: grpc: received message larger than max (3389524482 vs. 4194304)`

I'm fairly certain that the request I'm sending is below 4MB let alone 3GB.

I've tried using the gRPC client/stub generated from the protobuf schema and this seems to work.

I've compared the frames of the request sent by the client versus that I constructed myself, and everything seems to be the same.

Is there a particular frame that I should focus on for this type of error? (The code is proprietary so I won't be posting it.)

Comment: If you are pretty certain your message is not over 4 GB, then that probably means you are not properly formatting the `Length-Prefixed-Message` from https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md properly. The header is 5 bytes long and in big endian.

Comment: Wireshark is telling me that the gRPC message is malformed. This is the exact message: "Malformed message data: only 1131 bytes left, need at least 3389524477 bytes". The 1131 is the value of the Length header in the Data frame and represents the actual size of the message. Does this mean the Length-Prefixed-Message header is correct? If so, where is the 3389524477 bytes coming from?

Comment: Wireshark is seeing basically the same thing gRPC is seeing: a message whose size is supposed to be 3389524477 bytes. The 1131 bytes is how many bytes are left on the stream. That strongly agrees with my claim that `Length-Prefixed-Message` is encoded wrong.

Comment: You are right. The 5 bytes to represent the `Compress-Flag` and `Message-Length` fields were not being set during encoding. I guess I was expecting it to be done for me when invoking the `SerializeAsString()` method on the protobuf object but wasn't the case. Thank you.

Comment: This can also manifest itself as `only x bytes left, need at least 5 bytes.` in wireshark, if your payload is small.

Comment: @EricAnderson Why 4GB?

Comment: gRPC uses a 32 bit integer prefix on-the-wire representing the length of a message. gRPC is fine with large messages, but dealing with multi-GB messages will generally cause application-level problems so 2 (if not wanting to deal with signed integers, e.g., in Java) or 4 GB is deemed "plenty."